# Why I get the Error WhiteLabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I wrote simple web app

DemoApplication.kt

```html
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

Student.kt is a model

```html
package model

data class Student(
    val id: Int,
    val facultyId: Int,
    val name: String,
    val courseNumber: Int,
)
```

StudentDao.kt is a Dao class

```html
package example

import model.Student
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


class StudentDao: AbstractStudentDao {
    val data = listOf(
        Student(1, 2, "Peter Ivanov", 3),
        Student(2, 1, "Ivan Petrov", 1),
        Student(3, 1, "Vasiliy Smirnov", 4),
        Student(4, 2, "Vitaliy Kozlov", 2),
    )

    override fun getStudent(id: Int): Student {
        return data.filter{it.id == id}[0]
    }
    override fun getStudent(): List<Student>{
        return data
    }
}
```

StudentComponent.kt component of my model

```html
package example

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class StudentComponent(private val dao: AbstractStudentDao) {
    fun getExampleStudent(id: Int) = dao.getStudent(id)
    fun getExampleStudent() = dao.getStudent()
}
```

AbstractStudentDao.kt abstract for component

```html
package example

import model.Student
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface AbstractStudentDao {
    fun getStudent(id: Int): Student
    fun getStudent(): List<Student>

}
```

StudentController.kt finally it's controller

```html
package api

import example.StudentComponent
import model.Student

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/st")
class StudentController(val studentComponent: StudentComponent) {

    @GetMapping
    fun getStudent(): List<Student> {
        return studentComponent.getExampleStudent()
    }


}
```

Requests are created in the Controller based on the StudentComponent. I'm trying to get the right answer and I end up getting the whitelabel error. I realized that the error itself is due to the lack of error handling, but there is a fact that the error is related to the implementation. Could you please help me?

application.properties
server.port=8080

So, the error there is on `http://localhost:8080/st` URL

Comment: Does your application produce an error log? `Stacktrace`

Comment: I haven't got the error in logs, only in browser

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It looks like you have mapped all your context paths to `/st` when you are doing this:

```
@RequestMapping("/st")
```

Not too sure if you are getting the whitelabel error for `http://localhost:8080`. If that is the case, then try to hit `http://localhost:8080/st` instead.

That should resolve the issue. If not , put the URL in the question - the one you are trying to access and are getting the issue at.

Comment: Edited my question, for http://localhost:8080 there is this error. I found that there is this error for everything URL on this host and after making requests I have got 404 error in json response